# Множественное наследование через интерфейсы, работа с общими полями и свойствами

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, vb.net, оод

Планирую разделить один большой класс на 5 частей следующей стратегией.

```vb
Imports ConsoleApplication1

Module Module1

    Interface IA
        Function AFunc() As Integer
    End Interface

    Class A
        Implements IA

        Public Function AFunc() As Integer Implements IA.AFunc

            Return 1
        End Function

    End Class

    Interface IB
        Function BFunc() As Integer
    End Interface

    Class B
        Implements IB

        Public Function BFunc() As Integer Implements IB.BFunc

            Return 2
        End Function

    End Class


    Class AB
        Implements IA, IB

        Protected _a As New A
        Protected _b As New B

        Protected _somePropertyOne As String = "value1"

        Private _somePropertyTwo As String = "value2"
        Public Property SomePropertyTwo() As String
            Get
                Return _somePropertyTwo
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _somePropertyTwo = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Function AFunc() As Integer Implements IA.AFunc
            Return _a.AFunc()
        End Function

        Public Function BFunc() As Integer Implements IB.BFunc
            Return _b.BFunc()
        End Function

    End Class

    Sub Main()

        Dim ab As New AB

        Console.WriteLine(ab.AFunc)
        Console.WriteLine(ab.BFunc)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Возможно это и неправильно, но задача, требует на данном этапе реализовать разделение таким образом, чтобы все методы из набора подклассов, имели доступ к набору общих свойств (в данном случае `_somePropertyOne` и `SomePropertyTwo`)

Как это правильнее реализовать?

Куда перенести `_somePropertyOne` и `SomePropertyTwo`?

> В моем случае идеально подошли `Partial Class`

Comment: Я VB.NET знаю плохо, но я не вижу иерархии классов, поэтому не понятно, какие подклассы к чему должны получать доступ. Предположение: может. у методов сделать параметр, в который передавать значение свойства?

Comment: все в примере вообще то. вся иерархия классов и т.д.

Comment: Я вижу, что классы реализуют интерфейсы. Но ни один класс не является предком/потомком другого.

Comment: Задача в этом и заключается, изменить иерархию. Так что бы свойства стали доступны.

Comment: если знаете как реализовать это в C#, То я смогу перевести ваш код на VB.NET, есть инструменты. Например Instant VB (Free Edition)

Comment: Можно вместо кода(исходного), задачу на простом языке написать. А какое практическое применение всего этого?  И зачем вам это наслодование такое хитрое?

Comment: В тексте написано зачем, есть класс на 3000 строк, в нем методы, их надо разложить отдельно, но они все используют общий набор свойств.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, а partial-классы не подходят?

Comment: А я не знаю что это такое и как это использовать, боже неужели непонятно ) что ну не понимаю я как реализовать... Нет воообще ни каких мыслей. Кроме наследования ничего не приходилось использовать.... Если бы я знал хоть какие то варианты...

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь 1. вариант уже давно в ответе. 2. узнай.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй методы-расширения.

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Interface ICommon
    Property Value As Integer
End Interface

Public Module IAExts
    <Extension()> 
    Public Function FuncA(ByVal Obj As ICommon) As Integer
        Return 1 + Obj.Value
    End Function
End Module

Public Module IBExts
    <Extension()> 
    Public Function FuncB(ByVal Obj As ICommon) As Integer
        Return 2 + Obj.Value
    End Function
End Module

Public Class Smth
Implements ICommon
    Public Property Value As Integer Implements ICommon.Value
End Class

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim X As New Smth() With {.Value = 77}
        Console.WriteLine(x.FuncA())
        Console.WriteLine(x.FuncB())
    End Sub
End Module
```